# To Show that, $f$ cannot be expressed as the product of two polynomials with integer coefficients and degree $>1.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, proof-writing, irreducible-polynomials

$\textbf{Problem}$- Let, $f(x)=x^n+ax+p$, a $\in \mathbb{Z}.$ $p$ is a prime. Also, $p>|a|+1$. Show that, $f$ cannot be expressed as the product of two polynomials with integer coefficients and degree $>1.$

For this problem, which is a classical polynomial problem, I have been trying to apply the Vieta s theorem and irreducible criterion,but I can't structure my proof. A little bit rigorous proof is appreciable.
Thank you.

This problem has been lying unanswered... Kindly help ...I don't know why this problem is lying unanswered... Is there is any typo problem in the problem?

Comment: Can you use the rational roots theorem?  Since p is prime the rational roots theorem limits the possible roots.  Since you have $ax$ rather than $ax^2$ or some higher power, you have to try to find a factor in the form of $(x-r)$.

Comment: @IanJ can you kindly elaborate the last part..how to do that... How do we find (x-r) type factor

Comment: This problem is not done... Kindly answer anyone

Comment: But, with $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, since $p$ divides all coefficients (except of $x^n$), and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$, so $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and in particular, it implies your expectation. Isn't it what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you could factor the polynomial it must be in the form.  :

$$ (x^{bb}+... + b_1x + b_0)  (x^{cc} + ... + c_1x+c_0)$$

$$bb+cc = n$$
$$ b_0  c_0 = p$$
$$ b_1c_0 + b_0 c_1 = a$$

$$ p> |b_1c_0 + b_0 c_1|+1$$

Since p is prime you must iterate through the 4 possibilities for $b_0$ and $c_0$ :
{1,p}, {-1,-p}, {p,1}, {-p,-1}.

Plug these 4 possibilities into the inequality above and you'll see that the inequality cannot be satisfied with integer values for the $b_1$ and $c_1$.  Picking $b_1$ and $c_1$ from {1,-1} gets you  $|b_1c_0 + b_0c_1|$ only as small as $p-1$.

Comment: I have to think about how to prove that you can't just use a 0 for $c_1$ and/or $b_1$.